# Is there a difference between defining and declaring a type?

Tags: typescript

Is there a meaningful difference between using `declare type Foo = ...` (or `declare interface Bar { ... }`) and the same without the `declare` keyword, given that type aliases and interfaces don't exist outside the declaration namespace anyway?

Notably I'm interested if there's any gotcha involved in doing:

```
export declare namespace IUserService {
  interface CreateOptions {
    username: string;
    password: string;
  }
}

export interface IUserService {
  create(options: IUserService.CreateOptions);
}
```

Linter presets tend to complain about using internal modules / namespaces in non-legacy code because of the semantics clash with the now-recommended ES modules, since their purpose is - near as I can tell - to more straightforwardly represent how say CJS works.

That said, I find the above useful for specifically types only used to represent parameters and return values of class methods; I have many CRUD services with similar method names that would call for many different `CreateOptions` names, and it makes sense to me to just shove them under their owning interface's namespace rather than just giving them awkwardly long names.

Comment: That’s relevant to declaring variables, things that exist in the “value” namespace. I’m talking about what it does for TS-specific constructs that only exist in the “type” namespace.

Comment: Classes and namespaces are kind of weird in that they both exist in both the value and type namespaces. Namespaces are weirder yet in that if they don’t contain anything that itself exists in the value namespace, the namespace itself afaik doesn’t. (It definitely doesn’t if it’s `declared`, but then it’s a bad idea to declare a value inside it when the declaration isn’t describing something defined elsewhere.)

Comment: Since the question you linked is talking about declaring classes, it doesn’t really have much to do with what I’m talking about here, which is what the difference is between declaring vs. defining things that don’t exist in the value namespace. (Hopefully it’s not too confusing that I’m using “namespace” to describe both what the TS keyword means, and the concept from the design of the language differentiating things that exist in the transpiled JS at runtime, and things that only exist at compile-time.)